# Warning: Your Website Has Been Blacklisted

Tags: wordpress, block, malware

[image: Click here to view the screenshot]

This website run by wordpress. I change the main theme, remove all plugins, update all wordpress files. Don't know why but still face this problem. How to solve this problem? Please help...

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, the best is to:

- First: Take full backup of all your files.
- Second: Delete everything inside your Public_html directory (or
  wherever the wordpress in installed) except **wp-content** folder and
  **wp-config.php** file.
- Third: Download latest version of [wordpress](https://wordpress.org/download/) in your computer,
  extract it and archive all the folders expect wp-content and finally
  upload and extract it in public_html or wherever the wordpress is
  installed.
- Forth: Finally, install [WordFence](https://www.wordfence.com/) and scan the website.

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of a security scan, do at least two or three scans with various plugins to check your website. I have a strong feeling this scan you posted is just a scam trying to get you to install one of their antivirus programs.

I have tested your website on two computers with various antivirus and web shield programs and none of them blocked me from visiting your website. Your site passed [Google Safe Check](https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search?url=http:%2F%2Fhealthdoctorbd.com), [Spamhaus Check](https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/http%253A%252F%252Fhealthdoctorbd.com) and even Dshield Blocklist and your headers look fine to me on my side.

Do a scan using one of this plugins:

[WP Vulnerability Scanner](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-vulnerability-scanner/)

[WordFence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/)

And also check your site here on [HackerTarget](https://hackertarget.com/wordpress-security-scan/)